# "lumX" can live with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, lumx

some features like a dropdown does not work when you have added bootstrap css 
has anyone tried this tool?

```
<lx-dropdown>
    <button class="btn btn--m btn--black btn--flat" lx-ripple lx-dropdown-toggle>
        Dropdown toggle
    </button>

    <lx-dropdown-menu>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="dropdown-link" ng-click="dropdownAlert()">Notification</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-link">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-link">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><span class="dropdown-link dropdown-link--is-header">Header</span></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-link">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </lx-dropdown-menu>
</lx-dropdown>
```

Comment: Bootstrap has its own Dropdown widget, so yeah, they're probably conflicting.

Comment: Fine, anyway, reading about the Material tool i understood... the idea is use separately one of those, Material or Bootstrap and Material tool has some functional starter templates so it's ok
thank you